# Set default value for Placeholder in Tensorflow during training

Tags: tensorflow

I use Tensorflow 1, and defined `x` to be a `tf.placeholder` as one network input. But after training the network for some iterations, I want to fix the value of `x`, and don't set `x` in `feed_dict` when calling `sess.run(...)`. Is there any way to do so? One possible solution is setting a default value for `x`, but I cannot find a way in Tensorflow to add a default value for `tf.placeholder`. I cannot use `tf.placeholder_with_default`, because I don't know the default value when I define `x`, and also the default value may change during training.

---

The situation why I need this is as follows. I have a network `NN1(x1, x2)` with inputs `x1` and `x2`, and I trained this network. Then I want to define another network `NN2(x)` with only one input as `NN2(x) = NN1(x1=c, x2=x)`, where `c` is a constant. `NN2` should be encapsulated in this way (single input), so I can use it in my other codes.

Comment: Can you share your current code ?

Comment: what prevents you from still continuing to use `sess.run([...], feed_dict={x: default_value})`. `tf.Placeholders` are designed to be that way.

Comment: also you might want to look at `tf.Variable`

Comment: @Vedanshu I don't have a demo code. I need this function to link two pieces of codes.

Comment: @learner I cannot use `feed_dict` to set `x`, because my other code only allows single-input network. See more information I added.

Comment: i am assuming that in the network `NN1`, `x1` is set to be a placeholder. If that is the case, while loading your trained model, you can do `graph.get_tensor_by_name` to get this placeholder `x1` and set its value using `sess.run` where `sess` is from the loading code